# Update swt plugins on eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, swt-awt

I have an Eclipse 3.7.2 RCP application and I need to run this with JDK 7 on Mac OSX. I need SWT_AWT bridge fixes from SWT 4.3. Is there a way I can update to latest SWT in eclipse 3.7.2. The SWT binaries available [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000) are not plugins.

Comment: So? Just add the .jar to your classpath. If you don't know how, read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/how-to-import-swt-library-into-eclipse-workspace/).

Comment: @Baz As this is an Eclipse RCP the Eclipse version of the SWT plugins is included in the RCP build so you can't just change the classpath. Replacing the 3.7.2 SWT plugins with the 4.3 plugins is certainly not supported but might possibly work.

Comment: @greg-449 Fair enough, I missed that it's an RCP application.

Comment: It would be nice to upgrade just SWT and not the whole ecplise platform. Currently using Eclipse 3.8.2, and i would love to get my hands on SWT latest release, but not the 4.x eclipse IDE...

Comment: @marcolopes see my answer below. It works reasonably well to just "upgrade" SWT using the latest binaries and use them in your target platform. Beside small glitches (esp. on MacOS X) like the few ones mentioned, everything runs smoothly (incl. SWT_AWT).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is possible (and I did it in an application). Just download the correct fragments you need (for MacOS X, Win32, etc.) from the site you mention, put them in a folder, and add this folder to your target platform (just like you would do for the delta-pack). When building your product, Eclipse will pick the latest fragments from your folder instead of the 3.7.2 versions.
It basically works, but there are some incompatibilities or strange behaviors (like minimizing/maximizing icons not working, at least in my setup). Tell me if you had success in making SWT_AWT work in that setup under JDK 7, though, because I have had no luck so far.

Comment: How did you do that? I downloaded the zip from the site mentioned above and extracted the files into folder.  When I try to add this folder on my target platform, it lists zero plugins in the folder.